# How do you sort a list of tuple by one of the tuple-Haskell

Tags: haskell

I have a list of cards and want to sort list of cards([Card]) by suit but the way Card is defined makes it confusing to navigate. Can someone help me define a simple function to sort the list.

Tried things like :

```
sortHand ::[Card]-> [Card] 
sortHand hand = sort hand
```

but I can't figure out how to filter the suit only

Card is defined:

```
data Suit = Spade | Club | Diamond | Heart
  deriving (Eq, Ord, Enum, Bounded)

data Rank = Two | Three | Four | Five | Six | Seven | Eight | Nine | Ten
          | Jack | Queen | King | Ace
  deriving (Eq, Ord, Enum, Bounded)

data Card = Card Suit Rank
  deriving (Eq)
```

Comment: Have you tried adding `Ord` to the `deriving` clause for the `Card` type?

Comment: Read the first 2 paragraphs to understand how Ord is derived for user-defined datatype.
http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Ord.html

Comment: `sortHand = sortOn (\(Card s _) -> s)`.

Answer (score 3):

This is what the [`sortBy :: (a -> a -> Ordering) -> [a] -> [a]`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-14.11/base-4.12.0.0/Data-List.html#v:sortBy) and [`comparing :: Ord b => (a -> b) -> (b -> b -> Ordering)`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-14.11/base-4.12.0.0/Data-Ord.html#v:comparing) functions are for. The first lets you sort by a custom ordering, the other lets you define an ordering by mapping `a`'s to some `b` which has an ordering (a card to a suit in this example).

You could use these together to define

```
sortBySuit hand = sortBy (comparing $ \(Card suit _) -> suit) hand
```

Note however due to how the automatically derived `Ord` instances work your `Card` type would already be ordered by suit first and then rank if you just added a `deriving Ord` to your data definition.

Comment: Why `sortBy` and `comparing` when `sortOn` does the same thing in one function?

Answer (score 1):

This is easy if you make `Card` a *record type*:

```
data Card = Card { cardSuit::Suit, cardRank::Rank }
  deriving (Eq)
```

```
*Main> :m +Data.List
*Main Data.List> :m +Data.Ord
*Main Data.List Data.Ord> sortBy (comparing cardSuit) [Card Club Three, Card Diamond Two, Card Spade Eight, Card Spade Five]
[Card {cardSuit = Spade, cardRank = Eight},Card {cardSuit = Spade, cardRank = Five},Card {cardSuit = Club, cardRank = Three},Card {cardSuit = Diamond, cardRank = Two}]
```